# Generate multiple records based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

The case is that I have two models with relations many to many. But I want to make a query where I have the number of models multiplied by the relations where I have the same main model with one that has one relation. Here is the case in code:

```
# models/physician.rb
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

# models/patient.rb
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end

# models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

# models/extended_physician.rb
class ExtendedPhysician < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_one :appointment, foreign_key: 'physician_id'
  has_one :patient, foreign_key: 'physician_id', through: :appointment
end

# sql view created in scenic for extended_physician model
SELECT "physicians".* FROM "physicians"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "appointments" ON "appointments"."physician_id" = "physicians"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "patients" ON "patients"."id" = "appointments"."patient_id"


# schema
  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "physician_id"
    t.bigint "patient_id"
    t.datetime "appointment_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["patient_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_patient_id"
    t.index ["physician_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_physician_id"
  end

  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "physicians", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end


  create_view "extended_physicians", sql_definition: <<-SQL
      SELECT physicians.id,
      physicians.name,
      physicians.created_at,
      physicians.updated_at
     FROM ((physicians
       LEFT JOIN appointments ON ((appointments.physician_id = physicians.id)))
       LEFT JOIN patients ON ((patients.id = appointments.patient_id)));
  SQL

# test
RSpec.describe ExtendedPhysician, type: :model do
  describe 'patiens relation' do
    it 'retunrs correct patiens' do
      patient1 = Patient.create!
      patient2 = Patient.create!

      Physician.create!(patients: [patient1, patient2])

      expect(ExtendedPhysician.count).to eq(2)

      # this not pass because relations ids are same like [patien1.id, patient1.id]
      expect(ExtendedPhysician.all.map(&:patient).pluck(:id)).to eq([patient1.id, patient2.id])
    end
  end
end
```

And as you can see this test will not pass.
I would like to achieve exactly that this test passes it does not have to be a has_one relation it may be some method in the model but I do not know how to do it right

Comment: I don't even get what real world problem that view is supposed to solve. The appointments table is already working as a join table which creates a many to many relation between patients and physicians. You're joining two tables in that view thats you're doing absolutely nothing with - there will be no patient id in the view because you're not selecting it. And even so which patient id would it be? The first the last? Scrap it and rethink.

Comment: "But I want to make a query where I have the number of models multiplied by the relations where I have the same main model with one that has one relation" - that sounds like something you would do with a simple subquery or lateral join where you select aggregates like a COUNT from the joined table.

Comment: Why do you need `self.primary_key = 'id'`? And why do you need this test, it's rails code, and it is covered by tests

Comment: Your description seems complete gibberish. What do you actually mean by *number of models multiplied ... that has one relation*. Please post sample data and the expected results as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/v) - **no images**.